# `require': cannot load such file -- ffi (LoadError) `require': cannot load such file -- ffi (LoadError) when trying to start rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

Full stack trace:

```
/Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi (LoadError)
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sys-proctable-1.1.1-universal-darwin/lib/darwin/sys/proctable.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sys-proctable-1.1.1-universal-darwin/lib/sys-proctable.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /Users/galharth/Documents/productbattle/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/galharth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Rails version: 4.2.5
Ruby version: 2.3.0
Bundler version: 1.10.6
OSX: El Capitan (Co-worker using windows)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/65000467/12544391, e.g. adding `gem "ffi"` to `Gemfile` fixed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running `gem install ffi --platform=ruby`.

See [this issue](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/368) for more insight and resolution options.

Comment: Putting gem 'ffi' in the gemfile solve it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully install the `ffi` gem by running `gem install ffi --platform=ruby`, adding the line `gem 'ffi'` to my Gemfile`, and then running` bundle install`.